# Windows 7 not booting after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

When I choose windows 7 item in GRUB menu system is restarting and landing me again in grub menu.

Here is my [Boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9999810/).

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange,  for I had Win 7pro 64bit before and I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 paralell to it.  When I rebooted the PC asked me which System I want to run.  Did u perhaps Format u HDD before ?  If so then I suggest to reload Win 7 and then load Ubuntu 14.04.1 parall to it in the Workstation ( Arbeitsplatz ).  It will ask u in the Instalmenu,  how much HDD Space u want to save for Ubuntu.
I doubt that this is the answer u wanted,  but thatś how I did it.  So what do u have to loose,  just try it ;-)  I hope this will work for u,  good luck !!!  Just one last tipp,  keep ubuntu 14.04.1 lts,  don't update to 14.10 !!!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your grub file.

Please try the following:

1. Install grub-customizer `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`
2. Execute it (requires admin rights). `grub-customizer`
3. Navigate to the `General Settings` tab, and look for a category named `Visibility`.
4. Make sure all entries are ticked.

Also, check in the tab `List Configuration` to see if your Windows Installation is listed. If not, you might need to boot from a `Live CD` and use `boot-repair`.